# Changing Menu Tab Colors with Jquery

Tags: jquery, menu

I am trying to change the background color of a tab using jquery , the way i am doing is removing first class and then adding the other class which has a different background color inside my css, but there is a problem once a user hits a new tab he will be redirected to a new page so after page reload my tabs comes back to their default state.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is actually the common problem of the http) Usually you have to store those things on the server side (if it is not just a static html) or you can pass the selected index as the query parameter and then highlight the tab which index matches the seleced index passed.

Answer (score 0):

In a style tag or an imported css file put a rule like this:

```
#test-1 {'background-image' : 'none', 'background-color' : '#ff6666', 'font-weight' : 'bolder'}
#test-2 { /* whatever you want the second one to look like */ }
```

By using the ID selector for the css it should get a higher weight than the ui classes.  Give it a try and see.